# Feature update to Windows 10, version 1709 fails

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

When I try to install above upgrade the following is happening:

- Disable my Norton firewall and auto protect
     Clear the Windows update cache. Delete everything in C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download
- Run Windows Update troubleshooter
- Download the update. Must be massive file as it takes over 2 hours
- Prepare installation. Also takes around 2 hours
- Installation. White letters on pale blue background
- Computer restarts and begins with installation
- At around 20% progress it restarts again
- At progress 55% it restarts again Shortly after that the display goes black for a few seconds and when it comes back on it displays a message that it was **restoring to a previous version of Windows**

Does anyone know what the issue is or how I can find out what the issue is?

When I click on "Update history" in Windows Updater it only tells that the update "**failed to install**". I already know that :-)

I tried looking for an event log without success.
For now I have disabled the Windows Update service so that it doesn't constantly attempts download the update all the time

Comment: When this happened to me. I used windows 10 media creation tool and it worked. Get it [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/B/E/ABEE70FE-7DE8-472A-8893-5F69947DE0B1/MediaCreationTool.exe).

Comment: Run windows update troubleshooter to diagnose issue then upgrade again.
If no use, download clean 1709 iso from Microsoft website via media creation tool, execute in-place upgrade.

Comment: What Antivirus agent / DLP Agent is installed on this pc? Have you tried disabling all of them?

Comment: which error code do you see? Ms provides some steps to fix issues related to some error codes: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors

Comment: Norton 360 and I had disabled the firewall and its "Auto Protect"
NO ERROR code at all is visible

Will try:
  1. Run troubleshooter again then download. If it fails again
  2 Will run the media creation tool

Comment: in settings->windows update->history you see the error code

Comment: I tried again several times but with the same result :-( At 55% the system gets restored for some reason

According to Settings >> System >> About I have 
     Windows 10 Pro Version: 1703 OS Build: 15063.850 System type: x64-based processor

Which of these updates [Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=windows%2010%201703%20x64) do I have to install?

I've tried several of the files but always get an error "The update is not applicable to your computer"   

What am I doing wrong here?